# Enabling/Disabling certain textfields based on input

Tags: javascript, button, extjs, playframework

Problem: I have a number of textfields that are all disabled by default. And right now, I have it where if they click on a button 'Modify' that some of those text fields become editable.

Now, I have data being passed to those textfields and I want to get it where if a textfield contains a certain letter (ex. C or D) and they click on the 'Modify' button that it enables certain textfields and if it is any other letter and they click 'Modify' those fields will not be enabled

This is the current code that I have for enabling certain fields when 'Modify' is clicked.

```
buttonModify.on({'click': function (){
            var textF = Ext.getCmp('textfield1');
                textF.enable();
                textF.setReadOnly(false); 
                textF = Ext.getCmp('textfield2');
                textF.enable();
                textF.setReadOnly(false);
```

Is there a way where I can add a function where only enable tectfield2 when Modify is clicked if textfield1 contains the letters c or D? Otherwise, remain disabled.

Comment: Why did you use `java` tag?

Comment: Sorry must have happened by accident. I took the tag out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you want, or pretty close:

```
buttonModify.on(
    {
        'click': function (){
            var textF = Ext.getCmp('textfield1');
            textF.enable();
            textF.setReadOnly(false);
            var textValue = textF.getValue();
            if(textValue && Ext.isString(textValue) &&
                (textValue.toUpperCase().indexOf("C") != -1 || textValue.toUpperCase().indexOf("D") != -1))
            {
                textF = Ext.getCmp('textfield2');
                textF.enable();
                textF.setReadOnly(false);
            }
        }
    }
);
```